# Trigger an event seconds before the video ends in flowplayer?

Tags: flowplayer

I can trigger an event using onLastSecond function but I want a few more seconds earlier. Can it receive a parameter that identifies the seconds during which the event is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

You could just check where the playhead is:

```
$f().getTime();
```